# Dump all Raima db_VISTA Version 3.20 data to text

Tags: legacy, legacy-database, raima

A friend has an old program that no longer works but he wants to recover the data.

From the file's header I've found out that it's a legacy Raima db_VISTA Version 3.20 database.
I've found this similar question [How can I export data in a legacy DOS application when no export option is available?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/420762/how-can-i-export-data-in-a-legacy-dos-application-when-no-export-option-is-avail), but there's no answer that tell me how to dump the data to another format.

I've tried contacting Raima, but the forums seams dead (My topic wasn't even posted by the moderator)

[image: File's header]

[image: Folder structure]

**Do you know a tool that can help me export the data?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Raima has a program called dbexp.exe that can dump all raima data to text files.  Can you search to see if you have any of the Raima utilities?

Comment: I don't have any utility. Only the data files. Can you send it or point where can I get it?

Comment: Is this information extremely confidential?  I could try to export it for him ... we have all the raima utilities at work.  I'd need the DBD and all files.

Comment: I didn't see it.  I have a s.o. gmail account you could use.  jessstackoverflow is the user.

Comment: Ah, "dbexp" is what I'm searching for to view ancient data, thanks ;-)

Answer (score 1):

1. Ask for an evaluation [here](http://raima.com/download/?sdk&platform=LinuxARM). The `dbexp.exe` utility will be there.
2. Its documentation is [here](http://docs.raima.com/rdme/8_1/Content/RM/utilities/dbexp.htm).

Here is a post that explains what you want to do with an answer of Douglas Wilson (Raima) : http://forum.raima.com/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=1313

I hope it will help you.